# doublylinkedlist creating node

Tags: java, class, nested, private

I am working on a assignment in java that uses a generic type doubly linked lists. I'm sure this is a basic question but since I could not find the answer I thought I would ask.  Essentially the implementation of the doubly linked list class is given and all I am required to do is create some nodes. The problem I am having is that the node class is a private static nested class in the list class and I do not understand how I should be using it. The list class looks something like this (leaving out several get and set methods):

```
public class LinkedList<E> {

    private static class Node<E>{
        private E element;
        private Node<E> previous;
        private Node<E> next;

        public Node(E e, Node<E> p, Node<E> n) {
            element = e;
            prev = p;
            next = n;
       }

    }
}
```

In my driver class I use this:

```
    LinkedList <String> linkedlist = new LinkedList<String>();
    LinkedList.Node node = linkedlist.new Node();

    node n1 = new node("Amy", null, null);
```

Using this I get an error saying that LinkedList.Node should be changed to default visibility. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you do what the error message recommends?

Comment: @GeroldBroser It sounds like an Assignment and they are probably not allow to change the given code... that is assuming the Node implementation was given of course.

Comment: Don't access the nodes from outside the `LinkedList` class. Write all the code that is directly related to them, inside the `LinkedList` class instead.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it. The LinkedList class was given so I cannot make any changes. The assignment requires me to make a seperate driver class. Sorry i should have been more clear.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Lonenebula you don't want to access the `Node` class from outside of the `LinkedList` class.

To use the `LinkedList`, you don't create the node itself, but rather just add the element to the list. The internal code of the `LinkedList` class will hold all the required details on how to create a new node.

For example to add an element to the List you would have an `add(E e)` method. This method will then contain the logic to create the node and add it to the List. Within your list class you should already have the next and previous `Nodes` or have the logic to tell if it is the first or last `Node`.

At no point should you need to access the `Node` class from outside of the `LinkedList` class.

Comment: Unfortunately, the assignment is specific in that I'm supposed to first create the nodes then link them together rather than using the add methods. The linking would simply require me to set the next and previous of each node but I do not quite know how to create the nodes initially (I know that I would have to create the nodes for example with both next and previous set the null and the element defined e.g. "Amy").

Comment: @Learning Can you update the post to show how the question is worded and what is required? Also which `add` methods are you talking about? I didn't read about any in your post.